# Get Azure Storage Account Context in powershell - LazyAzureStorageContext vs AzureStorageContext

Tags: azure, powershell

Running the command bellow directly from a terminal session:

```sh
> $Context = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName  $ResourceGroupName -AccountName $StorageAccountName).Context
> $Context.GetType()
```

I get:

```sh
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    LazyAzureStorageContext                  Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.AzureStorageContext
```

When I use the same command within a Powershell script file I got a different object result, which is blocking me to upload files to the blob container.

```sh
function GetStorageContext() {
    Write-Host "Getting storage account context..."

    $conn = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName  $ResourceGroupName -AccountName $StorageAccountName).Context
    Write-Host $conn.GetType()
}
```

Outputs:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.LazyAzureStorageContext

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I too am having the same issue - I am trying to use the context to get a SAS token, and getting the error that LazyAzureStorageContext can't be converted to IStorageContext. I somehow got around that, but can't remember how, and am researching again. If/when I find the answer, I'll post the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't find the answer to your question. My issue was I was using the wrong PowerShell commandlet. Can you share the command you were trying to execute that was failing? LazyAzureStorageContext is a derived class of AzureStorageContext, so it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what is the difference between 2 objects you mentioned in the topic but I faced the same problem today and discovered that we should create new storage context with this command

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==>"
```

and then just append `-Context $context` to your next command.

More examples in [Azure Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontext?source=recommendations&view=azps-9.6.0)

Answer (score 0):

Try a command in PowerShell

`Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "RG01" -Name "storageaccount"`

Remember define Context

`Set-AzContext -Subscription "YOUR-SUBSCRIPTION`